# Multiple send, single recv

Tags: c, unix

I am confused by the mechanism of send and recv in unix programming:
If I use multiple send to send some strings to recv, and then use recv in which the buffer is big enough, sometimes I will get a whole string which is made of all of the strings from send, but sometimes I get only part of them. Why does it differ? How should I cope with this?

Comment: How would you like to cope with this? Why are you using "multiple send"? As it stands this question is both unclear and extremely broad.

Comment: Ideally there should be as many `recv()` as the no of `send()`. You shouldn't be mixing it up.

Comment: Take back my comment, the behavior is not predictable and needs to be handled in the code. Check my ans.

Comment: @dvnrrs I'm just curious about the mechanism and tried that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of distance, time and the things that happen in between.

Assuming you are talking about tcp, depending on various settings, you may do 5 `send`s before a packet ever goes out. Tcp has no notion of what your "string" is.  All it sees are a stream of bytes going and coming.

Maybe half your string arrives in one packet and your `recv` gets those bytes in one read.  But the second half of the string is in a second packet that gets lost and retransmitted or fragmented by some machine along the route into 2 packets.  You have no way of knowing.

So you construct your application to know your own message boundaries and you plan accordingly.  Messages, which are *only* meaningful to the application, have to be delimited by something (e.g. a newline) or be  prefixed with a length byte indicating how many bytes are in a message.  You recv until you get that number of bytes and can do something meaningful with the full message.

Comment: This is a decent answer. It might be helpful to emphasize the key that TCP is a *stream-oriented protocol*. You **must not** think in terms of packets when using TCP. Think instead in terms of a homogeneous stream of bytes. If you think and code this way, you shouldn't run into any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on how many TCP packets does it takes to fit your message. So, there is no defined behavior here, you need to handle it in your code as explained in this post: [c++ posix sockets recv functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286558/c-posix-sockets-recv-functionality)