# Trying to understand logic behind network communication

Tags: c, networking

In C, to receive/send data you usually do(roughly):

Server:

- Create socket
- Bind socket to port
- listen
- Accept
- Receive Send data

On client side:

- Create socket
- Connect
- Receive send

My question comes **after** server has done `accept`.

Imagine **after** `accept` on the server side there are three separate lines
to send data:

```
connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL ,NULL);
write(connfd, var1, var1Size);
write(connfd, var2, var2Size);
write(connfd, var3, var3Size);
```

Does this mean on the client side I need to have three reads?
Like this:

```
read(sockfd, &x, size1);
read(sockfd, &y, size2);
read(sockfd, &z, size3);
```

In other words how should send and receive calls correspond
on server and client side? Should for each send be a corresponding receive on the client side?

What if on client side, after 3 read calls(like above), I want to send data to server?
Shall I just add one new send and one new receive on client and server side respectively?

Should all these send/receives be happening within a single `accept` call context?

Here is a image to better illustrate what kind of scenario I could be interested in:

[image]

Pseudo code explaining how to handle this kind of connections would be welcome.

Comment: Assuming TCP, no - can read all sends with one read (depending on sizes).

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ posix sockets recv functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286558/c-posix-sockets-recv-functionality)

Comment: @sje397: yes, but what if I want to send data in chunks?

Comment: @dmcr_code Do the chunks mean anything ? Do the receiver need to separate one chunk from another ? If they do, you need to embed info in each chunks so they can be separated again, e.g. by adding a fixed number of bytes in front of each chunk that is the length of the chunk. The receiver might then take multiple recv() calls to receive a chunk (and it might get the end of one chunk and half of the beginning of the next chunk in one recv() call.

Comment: @dmcr_code - you send the size as e.g. two bytes then the message, read size at the other end then wait for that many bytes

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are working with a protocol which has a concept of "messages", e.g. UDP, all you have is a stream of bytes. You can send and receive them any way you wish.

You could, for example, send two 16-bit integers and receive them as one 32-bit integer. This is probably not what you intended but it's perfectly legal and used all the time in situations where it *is* needed. You can compose data structures on either side (sending and receiving) independandly, as long as it makes sense to your application.

Your bytes are sent in the order of your write()'s and you WILL receive them in the same order. I.e.

```
send(var1)  --->  recv(var1)
send(var2)  --->  recv(var2)
```

There is *no* way in normal TCP (barring unused edge cases which I'll not even specify because nobody should use them) that you will receive `var2` before `var1`.

TCP communication is bi-directional: each end-point (client and server) can send at the same time. It is up to you and your application to decide when to send and when to receive. The sending and receiving buffers are independant: you can send a few bytes, receive a few, send some more... and there will be no interference between them (i.e. you will not "overwrite" the receive buffer by sending some data nor vice versa).

I'll repeat it again: ALL you have in TCP is a *stream of bytes*. TCP doesn't know and doesn't care how these bytes are structured, neither on the sending nor on the receiving side. It's *ALL* up to you. When you send an integer or a data structure, you are sending a *memory dump* of those, *as bytes*.

For example, there's a common error where you attempt to `send()` a data structure and because the sending buffers are full, the system will make a partial write. If you do not check the return status of the `send()` call to detect this situation and then send the remainder of bytes *by yourself*, in another `send()` call, your client WILL be stuck in `recv()` when it expects the full structure and receives only a part of it, if you specify MSG_WAITALL.

Comment: 'Every operation will succeed' - or you will be notified of an error.

Comment: @Ivan Voras: Hey ivan, to illustrate better what I mean maybe let's look at such situation. Say server sends three ints to client using three separate send calls. How do I *distinguish* these variables on the client side? Shall I call three times receive on the client side and hope I receive integers appropriately?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, or you can create an array of three integers, or a structure which holds the three integers and receive that (if the client and the server are of exactly the same architecture and compiler), or you can create a byte buffer, or you can receive each byte individually, or anything else. It's up to you to interpret the data coming from the network, the system will not do that for you. tl;dr: yes, if you call send() on three integers, you can receive them by doing a recv() on three integers.

Answer (score 0):

1. TCP is a stream protocol, In the receiver side you cannot determine how many times the send has been called. Whenever recv is called it will give the number of bytes asked to read, if the requested number of bytes are not available then it will return the number of bytes currently in the socket buffer.
2. In case of UDP it will work as you mentioned, It is a datagram protocol. (use recvfrom to recv the data)

Comment: Worth noting, UDP packets can be received out of order and sometimes not received at all.